# My container isn't finding the package.json to execute npm install on docker-compose

Tags: linux, docker, npm, docker-compose

I'm trying to deploy an application using docker-compose and the app is in a folder in the host machine (in the same dir that the docker-compose file).

I'm runnig the command `docker-compose up -d`, however, it seems that the volume isn't mounting because when the command `npm install` is executed the following message is displayed:

```
Step 3/4 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in a09b1e8139ae
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
npm WARN app No description
npm WARN app No repository field.
npm WARN app No README data
npm WARN app No license field.
```

After that my container is exited.

My files:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  github-app:
    build:
      context: ./docker
    volumes:
      # Place app files.
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

**docker/Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10.15.1

WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't copy any of your context into your docker image in `dockerfile`, so yes, there's no files in the `/app` folder at the time you build the dockerfile. Docker-compose uses built docker images, so necessarily, building the dockerfile comes first, and you won't have any volumes at this point.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But in my case I'd like to use the files in my host machine, I'm not trying to copy the files into my docker image. Would it be possible to do that?

Comment: If you're trying to actively develop on your host machine, I'd just do the work there – run `npm install` or `yarn install`, and use the local `node_modules` directory for isolation.  What benefits are you hoping to get from using Docker here?

Comment: @DavidMaze I'd like to do that because this way I can edit the source files in the host machine but they are executing in containers. This way I don't need to install python, php, node and other stuff in my host machine. Did you get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless i am mistaken. the `docker` directory that responsible for the build process will be executed before mounting any volumes so the image during the build wont have any thing called `package.json` because its outside the context directory. try to move the `dockerfile` to the same root directory where you have `docker-compose.yml` and `package.json` and update the dockerfile with

```
COPY . /app
```

Instead of depending on the mounted volumes at it wont be available until the build is done

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now, it seems that the npm install is executing. But I'd like to know if it's possible to keep my app files in the host machine instead of copying them to the image. Besides that, my container keeps exiting after the steps. Is it common?

Comment: The container will exist if there is an error and this might be because there is no code there so npm can start. regarding keeping the file on the host you can copy only package.json inside the image then after starting the container use the node_modules folder

Comment: but would it be possible to have the node_modules and all the app files in my host machine? I mean, the container would execute the npm install but the node_modules would be created in the host machine. I asking this because I want to edit the source files in the host but this application would be executed in the conatiner. Dos it make sense?

Comment: Then you can do the installation process manually i am not sure if there is a reason to use Dockerfile in this case. for example on my own machine i have a nodejs image and i have created a container with my application mounted as a volume then i do npm install manually but this not an approach to use in a production envrionment